# Create maven project in Visual Studio Code (VScode) failing due to JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm using windows OS and installed VScode version 1.76.0.

When I select create java project with maven then I'm getting below error.

I already set the JAVA_HOME in my environment variables correctly.

I'm using **Maven for Java** extension in VScode as well.

I herewith pasted the VScode console log as shows below.

```
*  Executing task: "mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId="maven-archetype-quickstart" -DarchetypeGroupId="org.apache.maven.archetypes" -DarchetypeVersion="1.0" -DgroupId="com.helloman" -DartifactId="hello"" 

The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly, 
this environment variable is needed to run this program. 

*  The terminal process "cmd.exe /c "mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId="maven-archetype-quickstart" -DarchetypeGroupId="org.apache.maven.archetypes" -DarchetypeVersion="1.0" -DgroupId="com.helloman" -DartifactId="hello""" terminated with exit code: 1. 
*  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I tried with different archtypes also but got no success on that.

In windows CMD see JAVA home location by executing echo %JAVA_HOME% but without set JAVA_HOME in cmd manually the Maven is not identify the JAVA_HOME set in windows environment variables

Please refer to the below image

[image]

Comment: there is a semi colon in the original echo'd env variable. is this intentional?

Comment: Why are you using VSCODE for java? You should try intellij instead

Answer (score 0):

> The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
>
> this environment variable is needed to run this program.

The error message has reminded environmental variable `JAVA_HOME` incorrectly, please check the settings of *JAVA_HOME* in the system and user environment variables. Confirm that setting the correct *JAVA_HOME* environment variable and restarting VSCODE.

In addition, you can use the command to check whether you can succeed in the external terminal, which shows that it is not the problem of VSCODE.

Or you can manually set the correct Javhom variable with `set JAVA_HOME=<path\to\JDK>`.

Comment: I tired but still not working

Comment: Set `JAVA_HOME` in Maven settings.xml. [for example](https://pastebin.com/31xLz8aa).